# Determine regularity of transition matrix from diagram

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Hi I am doing an exercise where I have to sketch a diagram from a Markov process and then only from that sketch argue if the matrix is regular or not. The process is a happening on a square where clockwise transitions have the probability of a and anti clockwise transitions has zero probability. Also no transitions occurs on the diagonal, only between neighboring sites. My sketch looked something like this:

```
             a
       2 ----->->----   3
       |                    |
  a   |                    |  
       ^                   v   a
       |                    |
      1  ---<--<------4
             a
```

Only by looking at this sketch how am I supposed to determine if the transition matrix is regular or not?

Comment: If $\ a<1\ $ then your diagram cannot represent a Markov chain.  Either you must have $\ a=1\ $ or there must be be some other transitions missing from the diagram.  Should there be loops at each corner of the rectangle?  That is, does the chain remain in the same state with probability $\ 1-a\ $?

Comment: I understood it like that. Every corner is a state and the probability of going clockwise is a and anti-clockwise is 0. Nothing is mentioned about staying in the same state...

Comment: Then $\ a\ $ must be $1$ for the diagram to represent a Markov chain.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

As I pointed out in a comment, the diagram can represent a Markov chain only if $\ a=1\ $.

By definition, a Markov chain is regular if there is some power $\ P^n\ $ of its transition matrix $\ P\ $ whose entries are all strictly positive.  This means that if the chain starts off in state $1$ (say) with probability $1$ at a time $\ t=0\ $, then at time $\ t=n\ $ it has a positive probability of being in *any* of its states, since the probability of its being in state $\ i\ $ at time $\ t=n\ $ is just the $\ i^\text{th}\ $ entry in the first row of $\ P^n\ $ (assuming you're using row-stochastic transition matrices).

If the Markov chain represented by your diagram starts off in state $\ 1\ $ with probabiliity $1$ at time $\ t=0\ $, what possible states can it be in at time $\ t=4k+j\ $ when $\ j=1,2,3\ $ or $\ 4\ $?  Is there *any* time $\ t=n\ $ when it could have a *positive* probability of being in *every* one of its four states?